# How do I get the last BIOS time in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bios

I'm trying to make a program which makes and maintains a database of all the last BIOS times (the one seen in the task manager). However, I can't find a way to retrieve it through python. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You mean you want to see when the server booted for the last time?

Comment: Yeah, that's the one.

Comment: Hi, have you figured that out ? Trying to find the same answer here